# Visual Studio auto opening collapsed properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Here is my problem. I have a C# class file loaded in Visual Studio that I am working on. I made a class and created some properties inside of said class. I collapsed the properties like so:[image]

I collapse the properties with the little `+`/`-` button on the side of each. I want to collapse each of them since I have a lot of other classes with properties and I don't want to see a lot of repetitive code (get, set).

Closing them works fine but after I work on some other classes in the same file the properties re-open so I can see the code:

[image]

This happens relatively often and is quite annoying. I have a lot of lines in the file and I sometimes have to work with a small screen. Is this a glitch/bug or something else? (I am using Visual Studio 2010 C# Express)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you try to save the class before you go to another class and when you then come back is it the same. :)

Comment: Sorry its not working like that :(

Comment: have you thought about using the short cut Ctrl+M,O

Comment: @DJKRAZE I will try that now.

Comment: But that will collapse all of your regions and you need ctrl+M+L to expand all agin. If you need to collapse a particular region of code all the time look at my solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to solve this so far, but this does the trick. Press `CTRL-M` and then `O` and it will auto collapse everything in the current file you are on.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate tip to @DJKRAZE's excellent answer is Resharper. I use Resharper and it takes care of this automatically for me. For example if I write this code:

[image]

The 4 line property procedure causes a Expand/Collapse that is causing you grief.

Resharper makes it one line. When I delete the last curly brace (namespace) and enter it again, the code is automatically formatted (Edit > Advanced > Format Document doesn't do this):

[image]

Comment: Thanks. When I write my properties that only need a `get, set` I will put them on one line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
#region some_name
//your variables or code whatever
#endregion
```

And then you can collapse the particular code, and the good thing it does not open like the way it happens in your case.

See if that worked.